# What effect does executeUpdate() have on the JPA cache?

Tags: caching, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using OpenJPA.  If I want to do a mass delete/update using the executeUpdate() method, will the JPA cache be updated?  Or will this bypass the JPA cache?  When I say "cache", I am talking about both the L1 and L2 caches.  Does the type of query matter (native vs. JPQL)?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/docbook/manual.html#jpa_langref_bulk_ops) says:

> The persistence context is not synchronized with the result of the
>   bulk update or delete.
>
> Caution should be used when executing bulk update or delete operations
>   because they may result in inconsistencies between the database and
>   the entities in the active persistence context. In general, bulk
>   update and delete operations should only be performed within a
>   transaction in a new persistence context or at the beginning of a
>   transaction (before entities have been accessed whose state might be
>   affected by such operations).

So, since OpenJPA doesn't synchronize the L1 cache, I don't see why it would (and how it could) synchronize the L2 cache. He could flush it, but I doubt it. It's easy enough to test anyway.